# HTML+PHP в JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html

Как мне запихнуть вот этот большой блок в переменную javascript-a ???

```
<div class="bottom-content">
    <?php if ($product['options']) {
        //var_dump($product['options']);
        $option = $product['options'][0];
        //foreach($product['options'] as $option){
        if ($option['type'] == 'image') {
            $option_value = $option['product_option_value'][0]; ?>
            <a class="color-expand">
                <label class="label-variant">
                    <input onclick="cart.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"
                           class="label-variant label-variant-input" type="radio"
                           name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]"
                           value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"/>
                    <img title="<?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>"
                         src="<?php echo $option_value['thumb']; ?>"
                         alt="<?php echo $option_value['name'] /*. ($option_value['price'] ? ' ' . $option_value['price_prefix'] . $option_value['price'] : ''); */
                         ?>" class="img-option" width="30px" height="30px"/>
                    <input type="hidden"
                           id="model<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"
                           value="<?php echo $option_value['model'] ?>"
                    <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
                        <input type="hidden"
                               id="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"
                               value="<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>">
                    <?php } ?>
                    <p style="margin-left: 5px;  margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto;"
                       class="text-center"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?></p>
                </label>
            </a>
            <?php
        }
        // }
    } ?>
    <?php if ($product['manufacturer']) { ?>
        <p>
            <?php echo $text_manufacturer; ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $product['manufacturer']['href']; ?>">
                <?php echo $product['manufacturer']['name']; ?>
            </a>
        </p>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php
    // SERIES
    if (isset($product['series']) && !empty($product['series'])) { ?>
        <p>
            <?php echo $text_series; ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $product['series']['href']; ?>">
                <?php echo $product['series']['name']; ?>
            </a>
        </p>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php foreach ($product['attribute_groups'] as $attribute_group) { ?>
        <?php foreach ($attribute_group['attribute'] as $attribute) { ?>
            <?php if ($attribute['all']) { ?>
                <p>
                    <?php echo $attribute['name']; ?>
                    :
                    <span><?php echo $attribute['text']; ?></span>
                </p>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: И нужно прочитать про Twig. Крутой шаблонизатор. Сделает это. Сделает красиво. А то концентрация букв php - высока

Answer (score 1):

```
var foo = "этот ваш большой блок";
```

Comment: спасибо) как раз так делал, все получилось, я просто + их лепил, и применял <<<EOF, а всё гораздо проще оказалось)

Answer (score 0):

А в чем проблема запиxать в строку

```
let content = "ваш код"
```

А затем делайте что хотите